# How to include image in Message Box using ctypes in python

Tags: python-2.7, alert, ctypes, windows-7-x64

I am making an message box in python 2.7 on windows 7 64 bit machine. It will rise to show error message to user in message box.

```
import ctypes

msgbox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
ret = msgbox(None, 'message', 'title', 0)
print ret
```

This shows the required message box. But in **taskbar the default image of python appears** which is annoying. So, **how to include image in taskbar. Or just not to show default image of python in taskbar**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't have a window, `None`, and then the system will assign a default icon.

You can install a hook using `SetWindowsHookEx` and then alter `MessageBox` icon. For example let's use [StackOverflow icon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico).

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!python


from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
#recommended
#from ctypes import windll, c_int, c_int64, c_long, WINFUNCTYPE, POINTER, cast, c_wchar, byref
#from ctypes.wintypes import HMODULE, LPCWSTR, HANDLE, HINSTANCE, UINT, HWND, WPARAM, LPARAM, HHOOK, DWORD, BOOL, RECT, POINT
from os import path
import platform

#################################################################

RelPath = lambda file : path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), file)

#################################################################

GetModuleHandle = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandle.restype = HMODULE
GetModuleHandle.argtypes = [LPCWSTR]

#################################################################

IMAGE_ICON = 1
LR_LOADFROMFILE = 0x00000010
LR_CREATEDIBSECTION = 0x00002000

LoadImage = windll.user32.LoadImageW
LoadImage.restype = HANDLE
LoadImage.argtypes = [HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR, UINT, c_int, c_int, UINT]

#################################################################

LRESULT = c_int64 if platform.architecture()[0] == "64bit" else c_long

SendMessage = windll.user32.SendMessageW
SendMessage.restype = LRESULT
SendMessage.argtypes = [HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM]

#################################################################

MB_OK = 0x00000000L 

MessageBox = windll.user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox.restype  = c_int
MessageBox.argtypes = [HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT]

#################################################################

WH_CBT = 5
HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
HOOKPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)

SetWindowsHookEx = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW
SetWindowsHookEx.restype = HHOOK
SetWindowsHookEx.argtypes = [c_int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD]

#################################################################

CallNextHookEx = windll.user32.CallNextHookEx
CallNextHookEx.restype = LRESULT
CallNextHookEx.argtypes = [HHOOK, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM]

#################################################################

GetCurrentThreadId = windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId
GetCurrentThreadId.restype = DWORD
GetCurrentThreadId.argtypes = None

#################################################################

UnhookWindowsHookEx = windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx
UnhookWindowsHookEx.restype = BOOL
UnhookWindowsHookEx.argtypes = [HHOOK]

#################################################################
# code starts here

def MyMessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType, lpIcon):
  hHook = HHOOK(None)

  #**********************************************************#
    # center button code
  def EnumChildProc(hwnd, lParam):
    ClassName = (c_wchar * 7)()
    if GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, 7) > 0:
      if ClassName.value.lower() == "button":
        wrect = RECT()
        GetClientRect(lParam, byref(wrect))
        brect = RECT()
        GetClientRect(hwnd, byref(brect))
        bpoint = RECT()
        MapWindowPoints(hwnd, lParam, cast(byref(bpoint), POINTER(POINT)), 2)
        MoveWindow(hwnd,
                  ((wrect.right - wrect.left) - (brect.right - brect.left)) // 2,
                  bpoint.top,
                  brect.right - brect.left,
                  brect.bottom - brect.top,
                  True)
        return False
    return True
    
  WNDENUMPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, LPARAM)

  EnumChildWindows = windll.user32.EnumChildWindows
  EnumChildWindows.restype = BOOL
  EnumChildWindows.argtypes = [HWND, WNDENUMPROC, LPARAM]

  GetClassName = windll.user32.GetClassNameW
  GetClassName.restype = HWND
  GetClassName.argtypes = [HWND, LPCWSTR, c_int]

  GetClientRect = windll.user32.GetClientRect 
  GetClientRect.restype = BOOL
  GetClientRect.argtypes = [HWND, POINTER(RECT)]
  
  MoveWindow = windll.user32.MoveWindow
  MoveWindow.restype = BOOL
  MoveWindow.argtypes = [HWND, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int, BOOL]
  
  MapWindowPoints = windll.user32.MapWindowPoints
  MapWindowPoints.restype = c_int
  MapWindowPoints.argtypes = [HWND, HWND, POINTER(POINT), UINT]
    
  #**********************************************************#

  def AlterIcon(_hWnd, lpszIcon):

    WM_SETICON = 0x0080
    ICON_BIG = 1

    hModel = GetModuleHandle(None)
    hIcon = LoadImage(hModel,
                      RelPath(lpszIcon),
                      IMAGE_ICON,
                      0, 0,
                      LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)


    SendMessage(_hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, hIcon)

  def CBTProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    if nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE:
      _hWnd = cast(wParam, HWND)
      AlterIcon(_hWnd, lpIcon)
      #**********************************************************#
      pEnumChildProc = WNDENUMPROC(EnumChildProc)
      EnumChildWindows(_hWnd, pEnumChildProc, _hWnd.value)
      #**********************************************************#

    CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    return 0

  # WARNING: don't pass HOOKPROC(CBTProc) directly to SetWindowsHookEx
  pCBTProc = HOOKPROC(CBTProc)

  hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, pCBTProc, None, GetCurrentThreadId())

  MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType)

  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook)

# example of usage
MyMessageBox(None, "Hello world!", "Title", MB_OK, "favicon.ico")
```

Most the code is just functions prototype. Now you can call `MyMessageBox` as:

```
MyMessageBox(None, "Hello world!", "Title", MB_OK, "favicon.ico")
```

result:

[image]

**UPDATE**: it will center the button now by enumerating through the message box window's chillers and looking for a button, then center it. I haven't test it much but it looks OK so far.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I doubt, how to use this code as a function, so that many time  it is callable with different text messages.

Comment: @winterfall OK, I modified the code and wrapped these functions inside a single `MyMessageBox` function.

Comment: thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. Can this ok button be moved to center. I added the screenshot of alert box where ok button comes at end. Can it moved to center

Comment: @winterfall There is no direct way to do this (it depends on the system and the theme I guess). I modified the code so it centers the button, it works well on Windows 7 but I haven't test it on other versions.

Comment: @winterfall Yes I use 32bit Windows 7.

Comment: Alert box is displayed, BUT the alert pop-up is NOT getting highlighted on the top of the window screen. Manually, I have to click on image on taskbar to see the alert box. How to resolve this. Please suggest.